# How to preserve order of selectInput variables on restore?

Tags: r, shiny

I noticed that the selectinput options are not ordered the right way when restoring the app from a bookmark. I found that this is a [known issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1490). However, I'm trying to find a way to workaround this. For example, in the screenshot below I entered in order 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, and 1. But on restoring it, the order defaulted to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Code**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    verticalLayout( 
      div(style = "height: 20vh"), 
      div(style = "height: 40vh;", 
          htmlOutput("text", style = "text-align: center;")
          ),
      div(style = "display: flex; justify-content: center;",
          div(style = "display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;",
              selectInput("vars",
                  "Select variables",
                  multiple = TRUE,
                  choices = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)),
              bookmarkButton())
      )))
}

server <- function(input, output) {
 
    output$text <- renderText({
      paste0("<p>", input$vars, "</p>")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read [*Advanced bookmarking*](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/advanced-bookmarking.html), it hints at the ability to override the normal behavior by using `onRestored`. Two changes: add `session` to your server component, and add an `onRestored()` block.

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    verticalLayout(
      div(style = "height: 20vh"),
      div(style = "height: 40vh;",
          htmlOutput("text", style = "text-align: center;")
          ),
      div(style = "display: flex; justify-content: center;",
          div(style = "display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;",
              selectInput("vars",
                  "Select variables",
                  multiple = TRUE,
                  choices = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)),
              bookmarkButton())
      )))
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  onRestored(function(state) {
    updateSelectInput(session, "vars", selected = state$input$vars)
  })
  output$text <- renderText({
    paste0("<p>", input$vars, "</p>")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

(I also tested this with `onRestore` (no trailing `d`), and it worked there as well. The documentation clearly suggests using `onRestored` for calling `update*` functions, so I'll go with that without knowing precisely why.)